# reseting rest pose is offsetting my armature and model

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, pose-mode

I am trying to make a new rest pose for my character (T-pose) for unity, but when i try to POSE_APPLY_ REST POSE this happens.[image] As you can see my hand and finger bones do not match up with the model. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in pose mode pose your character where you want to be the new rest pose, then select the mesh and apply the armature modifier, then select the armature and, in pose mode, apply the pose as rest pose; then re-parent your mesh to the armature, using Ctrl P > armature deform, so to retain the previously maden vertex weights.