# Vertex groups (mesh) is broken after rotate in pose mode and apply to rest pose

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, pose-mode

How to bind it again follow current bone offset

Before edit pose
[image: 1]

After edit pose and apply
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Please include images in your question rather than posting links to them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Your image links are all broken. Please use Stack Exchange's own image hosting instead. Also, the Imgur embed code you added to your post will not work here.

Comment: nice now i know how to show the images thanks :D

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53911/reseting-rest-pose-is-offsetting-my-armature-and-model/53920#53920

Comment: thanks but it not work with me the vertex groups not recaculate new offset with bone :v mesh still broken